# Disable rigidbody on a specific gameobject using C# and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble in my pinch code because it also grabs my player. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Leap;
using Leap.Unity;

/** 
* Detects pinches and grabs the closest rigidbody if it's within a given range.
* 
* Attach this script to the physics hand object assinged to the HandController in a scene.
*/
public class MagneticPinch : MonoBehaviour {

public const float TRIGGER_DISTANCE_RATIO = 0.7f;

/** The stiffness of the spring force used to move the object toward the hand. */
public float forceSpringConstant = 100.0f;
/** The maximum range at which an object can be picked up.*/
public float magnetDistance = 0.5f;

protected bool pinching_;
protected Collider grabbed_;
public GameObject TrashAudio;

public GameObject myPlayer;

void Start() {
    pinching_ = false;
    grabbed_ = null;

}

/** Finds an object to grab and grabs it. */
void OnPinch(Vector3 pinch_position) {
        pinching_ = true;

    // Check if we pinched a movable object and grab the closest one that's not part of the hand.
    Collider[] close_things = Physics.OverlapSphere(pinch_position, magnetDistance);
    Vector3 distance = new Vector3(magnetDistance, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    for (int j = 0; j < close_things.Length; ++j) {
        Vector3 new_distance = pinch_position - close_things[j].transform.position;
        if (close_things[j].GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null && new_distance.magnitude < distance.magnitude &&
            !close_things[j].transform.IsChildOf(transform)) {
            grabbed_ = close_things[j];
            distance = new_distance;

        }
    }
}
/** Clears the pinch state. */
void OnRelease() {
    grabbed_ = null;
    pinching_ = false;
    TrashAudio.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    //ActivateRigidbody ();
}

/**
* Checks whether the hand is pinching and updates the position of the pinched object.
*/
 void Update() {
    bool trigger_pinch = false;
    HandModel hand_model = GetComponent<HandModel>();
    Hand leap_hand = hand_model.GetLeapHand();

    if (leap_hand == null)
        return;

    // Scale trigger distance by thumb proximal bone length.
    Vector leap_thumb_tip = leap_hand.Fingers[0].TipPosition;
    float proximal_length = leap_hand.Fingers[0].Bone(Bone.BoneType.TYPE_PROXIMAL).Length;
    float trigger_distance = proximal_length * TRIGGER_DISTANCE_RATIO;

    // Check thumb tip distance to joints on all other fingers.
    // If it's close enough, start pinching.
    for (int i = 1; i < HandModel.NUM_FINGERS && !trigger_pinch; ++i) {
        Finger finger = leap_hand.Fingers[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < FingerModel.NUM_BONES && !trigger_pinch; ++j) {
            Vector leap_joint_position = finger.Bone((Bone.BoneType)j).NextJoint;
            if (leap_joint_position.DistanceTo(leap_thumb_tip) < trigger_distance)
                trigger_pinch = true;
        }
    }

    Vector3 pinch_position = hand_model.fingers[0].GetTipPosition();

    // Only change state if it's different.
    if (trigger_pinch && !pinching_)
        OnPinch(pinch_position);
    else if (!trigger_pinch && pinching_)
        OnRelease();

    //this line of code is a self scripting for disabling the rigidbody from the player component
    // Accelerate what we are grabbing toward the pinch.
    if (grabbed_ != null) {
            Vector3 distance = pinch_position - grabbed_.transform.position;
        //DeactivateRigidbody ();   //this is not to grab the rigidbody of the player
            grabbed_.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (forceSpringConstant * distance);
            TrashAudio.gameObject.SetActive (true);
            //DeactivateRigidbody ();
    }
}
}
```

Every object must have a rigidbody that is set to **USE GRAVITY** so my player as well so that it will not go through my terrain . My script is grabs the nearest object that has a rigidbody. The problem is when I grab some object its always grab itself I mean my player. I'm using a leap motion to grab.

So how can I obtain that if my script detects that it is grabbing my player it will stop grabbing but instead grab the object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using 
//attach this script to pinching
     void DeactivateRigid(){

```
 myPlayer.Getcomponent<Rigidbody>().isKenimatic == false;
 myPlayer.Getcomponent<Rigidbody().detectCollision = true;
 }
```

//attach this script to release

```
 void ActivateRigid(){
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Unity is a bit rusted but you can attach a tag to GameObject, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-tag.html

Be sure to tag the player as a player, afterwards you could use a check whether the nearest gameobjects tag isn't "player".

Comment: tried it but doesn't do anything still grabs my player

Answer (score 0):

Really easy.
You can tag your player like player like in image: [image]

then add to your code something like this into the method `OnPinch`

```
 // Check if we pinched a movable object and grab the closest one that's not part of the hand.
Collider[] close_things = Physics.OverlapSphere(pinch_position, magnetDistance);
Vector3 distance = new Vector3(magnetDistance, 0.0f, 0.0f);

for (int j = 0; j < close_things.Length; ++j) {
 if(close_things[j].gameobject.Tag.ToUppercase() == "PLAYER")
    continue; //here you jump to a the next object
```

PS: Or you can simply use a different layer that ignore the player

Comment: tried it already but still grabs my player. haha but thanks anyway >.< any idea ???

Comment: have you used a mask filter to your sphere overlap?

Comment: I had the same problems :) 
Reading well your code I'm sure that my solution will works.

 if (grabbed_ != null) { 
...}
try to debug this variable you here shouldn't have the collider on gameobject with "Player" Tag.